# Ошибка при SQL запросе с использованием DATE_FORMAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

sql запрос в php

```
$query = "SELECT `ID_CityFiling` , DATE(`Date_Reg`) AS 'Date_Reg', DATE_FORMAT(`Date_OfFiling`,'%d.%m.%Y') AS 'Date_OfFiling', `VisaType` , ROUND(`Cost`,0) AS 'Cost'
            FROM `%s`
            WHERE `Registered` = 25 AND `Date_Reg` > '{$dateWith}' AND `VisaType` != '7'
            ORDER BY date(`Date_Reg`) DESC, `ID_CityFiling` DESC, `VisaType`  DESC, `Date_OfFiling` ASC, `Cost`  DESC";
```

Если его выполнить в mysql, то он работает и всё отображает.
Акцент на

> DATE_FORMAT(`Date_OfFiling`,'%d.%m.%Y')

Но если в php делать запрос. То в ответ ничего не получаю.
Подозреваю, что ошибка в синтаксисе ковычек скорей всего. 
Если вместо DATE_FORMAT использовать DATE(`Date_OfFiling`), то всё работает корректно.
Подскажите где сделал ошибку

Comment: Показывайте СОДЕРЖИМОЕ переменной $query после всех подстановок, а не код его сборки.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE_FORMAT(`Date_OfFiling`,"%d.%m.%Y")
```